# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on ubunto WSL

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I am trying to access the core dumped file to start debugging but it never shows.

I tried many solutions such as:

- Giving it a size  `ulimit -c unlimited`
- making the directory writable so it can create such file
- I checked the  `sysctl kernel.core_pattern` 
  but ends
  `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern: No such file or directory`
  probably it didn't create any core files anywhere although it produces me core dumped
- I though its a problem with system so I tried [this link](https://blog.opstree.com/2019/04/02/resolving-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-ubuntu/) in which I cleared the locks and repository cache and updated the apt-get and nothing happened at the end

I dont know whats the problem if someone could explain me this and help me with a solution

Comment: Possibly [this known bug in WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1262)?

Comment: Probably, I'll install ubuntu on sth else and try it and wish it works. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The statement that works with g++ and C++ multithreading (with pthread.h) is :

```sh
g++ -static -pthread -D_GLIBCXX_GTHREAD_USE_WEAK=0 -std=c++0x -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive <yourCode.c>
```

Thanks to https://www.medo64.com/2021/05/segmentation-fault-using-threads-with-static-compile/